# How does the --touch flag for snakemake work exactly?

Tags: snakemake

I am running a big snakemake workflow on a cluster and for bug fixing I had to update a specific rule. I do not want to recreate every file that has been created before the update. Just those that were not created. When I just start the workflow snakemake wants to update these files too. So I added the `--touch` flag. This is failing as soon as it hits a file that has not been created yet.

Can someone explain how the `--touch` flag works exactly? Is this supposed to happen this way? Is there a way to apply `--touch` only to files, that have already been created? Maybe be combining with `--forceall`?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: *This is failing as soon as it hits a file that has not been created yet*: Yes, this is the way the `--touch` flag should behave according to the documentation "*Fails if a file does not yet exist*". However, I [reported](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1680) an inconsistency between docs and behavior since I found snakemake *does not* fail in such cases - strange... Can you give more detail about the snakemake version and a minimal example?

Comment: Hey, thanks for you reply. I am using Snakemake 7.8.2. This error occurred with a variant call pipeline (https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/dna-seq-gatk-variant-calling) with some minor adjustments to run on a slurm cluster.